# REST endpoint simulation via ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

If I have the below endpoints configured in my ExpresssJS config file server.js

```
// Generic    
app.post('/mycontext/:_version/:_controller/:_file', (req, res) => {
      const {_version,_controller,_file} = req.params;
      const mockDataFile = path.normalize(path.join(mockRoot,`${_version}/${_controller}/${_file}.json`));
    });

// Specific    
    app.post('/mycontext/v1/mycontroller/myendpoint', (req, res) => {
    
    });
```

For an endpoint invoked from UI as say /mycontext/v1/mycontroller/myendpoint, which of these 2 would get mapped ? Does the order of defining these configs matter in any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is first come first serve.

`ExpressJS` calculates the priority of a route based on the specificity of its path and the order by which they are declared. Routes are ordered from the most specific to the less specific one.

the first one will be hit:

```
app.post('/mycontext/:_version/:_controller/:_file', (req, res) => {
      const {_version,_controller,_file} = req.params;
      const mockDataFile = path.normalize(path.join(mockRoot,`${_version}/${_controller}/${_file}.json`));
    });
```

Bear in mind that in `ExpressJS` there's no built-in way to declare our routes as a list ordered by priority.

Although, You can declare `specific routes` always before `generic routes` as a best practice.

Comment: Thanks a lot...though I am slightly confused...coz in terms of specificity, the 2nd one would be more specific (i.e. '/mycontext/v1/mycontroller/myendpoint')

Comment: it works like middlewares, it will respond as soon as it matches the route and doesn't care what is the next route(s)

Comment: You should declare specific ones before generic ones as a best practice.